# Lego Mindstorm NXT cannot connect via bluetooth

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, bluetooth

I have an NXT mindstorm brick, running RobotC firmware. I am trying to connect to it, via bluetooth. At first, the problem was that I had the motorola drivers instead of ones from microsoft. Even after uninstalling he motorolla drivers and replacing them with stack microsoft drivers, the NXT cannot be found by the PC. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the NXT brick when the original firmware is loaded (rather than the RobotC firmware)? Have you got any other BT devices that you can pair with (i.e. a phone/headset/etc) just to check it's not an issue with the BT hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've tried this, but hopefully it will help someone. Make sure that your computer has been added to the brick's trusted devices **and** your brick has been added to your computer's trusted devices. I haven't got the link to work with "anonymous" devices before; you need to go through the process of entering the PIN.

Answer (score 2):

Also - check what device you are working with.  I know the iPhone doesn't recognize the NXT because it's not an "officially supported" Bluetooth device.  The only way to get your iPhone or iPod to work is to "jailbreak" them.  I'm not too sure if this extrapolates to all apple products either.

I would agree with the user above.  Revert to the original firmware that came on the NXT and try to connect with it.  I would add that if you can't connect, I would also try USB or another device.  Your computer you are using to try to communicate with might be having issues with Bluetooth.

O yeah, and if it works I would just recommend using a compiler that just sends NXT native direct commands down to the device (C# with Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio for example, or VB.NET).  That way you don't have to mess around with the NXT firmware.

For a great comprehensive over-view of the bluetooth (and USB) direct NXT commands, there is a great writeup here:
http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/Programming-LEGO-NXT-Mindstorms/92.html
I would recommend checking it out as its much better than the one that LEGO provides!

Hope this helps!